# unable to remove a program

Tags: package-management, software-center, dpkg

I'm trying to remove `bitdefender` using the ubuntu software center.. and this is what happened next:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ...
(Reading database ... 188880 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing bitdefender-scanner:i386 ...
find: `/opt/BitDefender-scanner/share/locale': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing bitdefender-scanner:i386 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bitdefender-scanner:i386
Error in function:
```

what should i do??

Comment: did something happen to your `/opt/BitDefender-scanner/share/locale' , is it still there? Appears to be the subject of an error.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to re-install the Bitdefender package to restore missing files and folders, then uninstall it.

Comment: @Xen2050 - no-----

Comment: @DavidFoerster - can u tell me how to do that..i'm a new user so i don't know much.. :(  <br/>  i try to fix the broken package with synaptic package manager but it did'nt work..

Comment: Well, how did you install Bitdefender in the first place? Just do it all again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution to this except the following:

Open terminal and type

```
cd /opt
```

then run this

```
sudo rm -r BitDefender-scanner
```

This will remove the directory as a root

Now when you will open synaptic package manager, there will be no problem.

Comment: -1 I beg to differ about the first statement (see my comments). Also, the package manager will still complain, because then there's going to be an installed package missing the majority of its files.